# Would my argument of knowledge being a social construct be a resolution to The Problem of the Criterion?

Tags: logic, epistemology, necessity

Questions from https://iep.utm.edu/problem-of-the-criterion/:

> What do we know?
>
> How are we to decide in any particular case whether we have knowledge?

I’ve been reading into The Problem of the Criterion, and I interpret that the second question may be synonymous with the expression “How do you know the answer to question 1 is true?” because the particular case presented is knowledge about anything and all things, whereby it’s being questioned how can you decide in that case (which is a particular case of any particular cases) whether or not you have knowledge in relation to such, which seems to me to be synonymous with the expression “How do you know that is true”

Am I right on my interpretation of how the second question may be interpreted?

**My resolution**:

If I argue that knowledge is a social construct, then I may argue in favor in social contract theory, whereby whether or not a statement is taken as true may be dependent upon whether or not people agree upon such statement being true in order to have utility from accepting such theory as sound and valid until it is falsified. My answer would then be utilitarian, whereby based on its utility for social persons under social contract theory, it would be knowledge rather than a theory. I think the problem with claiming knowledge to be a social construct would be how I know that to be true: Would such be a problem, thus indicating that I have not escaped The Problem of the Criterion?

My theory as to the answer to question 1 ("What do we know?") is the following based on the belief that such is socially useful: We know that which we are able to satisfy the one or more necessary or sufficient criteria to have knowledge of.

Comment: Is the "problem of the criterion" a real problem? Can't we just define "knowledge" as what comes out of e.g. an empirical scientific process (as one type of knowledge)? "scientific knowledge" would be "that which the scientific process produces" (for example). What am I missing?

Comment: No. How do you know that people agree on whatever it is? You conducted a poll? How do you know that people understood the question and answered truthfully? Or that poll workers/software can be trusted? Or what "social contract" even means, for that matter? *This* is the problem of the criterion: you need to already have a criterion to set up any criterion. Whether knowledge is JTB or social contract makes no difference whatsoever, and there is no "*resolving*" it. [Less Wrong](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/Xs7ag4gsiA6zspmsD/the-problem-of-the-criterion) surveys some typical *responses*.

Comment: Five sigmas is the criterion. Coherentism is just fine and we can move on.